# Regular Expression for formatting numbers in Vue2

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to print an integer in Vue2 with commas as thousands separators. For example, I want to show the number 34567 as "34 567". How would I go about doing this?

```js
<v-carousel-item
        v-for="item in RANDOM_PRODUCTS"
        :key="item.id"
    >
 <span
    class="name_item_price"
 >
   {{ item.price[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1 ') }}
 </span>
</v-carousel-item>
```

This option used to work, but now it gives an error on some pages.
Error:

**Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply common text formatting.

```js
<span
    class="name_item_price"
>
    {{ item.price[0] | capitalize }}
</span>
```

define a filter globally before creating the Vue instance:
**main.js**

```js
Vue.filter('capitalize', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  value = value.toString()
  return value.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1 ')
})
```